How to gnuplot csv file with data columns including square brackets
I have large datafile in csv format.
#data and time, id, volt, temp
2024-04-11 18:15:11,1,[3100,3295,...,3120],[29,27,...,30]
2024-04-11 18:15:11,4,[3100,3295,...,3120],[29,27,...,30]
2024-04-11 18:15:11,5,[3100,3295,...,3120],[29,27,...,30]
2024-04-11 18:15:11,6,[3100,3295,...,3120],[29,27,...,30]
2024-04-11 18:15:11,7,[3100,3295,...,3120],[29,27,...,30]
2024-04-11 18:15:11,10,[3100,3295,...,3120],[29,27,...,30]
2024-04-11 18:16:11,1,[3100,3295,...,3120],[29,27,...,30]
2024-04-11 18:16:11,4,[3100,3295,...,3120],[29,27,...,30]
2024-04-11 18:16:11,5,[3100,3295,...,3120],[29,27,...,30]
2024-04-11 18:16:11,6,[3100,3295,...,3120],[29,27,...,30]
2024-04-11 18:16:11,7,[3100,3295,...,3120],[29,27,...,30]
2024-04-11 18:16:11,10,[3100,3295,...,3120],[29,27,...,30]

...
greater than 200000 rows!
There are 416 values in each of those brackets. The values change as the time goes.
The numbers of 1,4,5,6,7,10 are reference of six fixed equipment tag and are repeated for each minute of time
Above is an example of 18:15:11 and then the same id numbers 1,4,5,6,7,10
How would i be able to plot these in gnuplot?
I think a basic plot and then something similar to fence plot but stacked would be nice.
Thanks
Sina
Well I am stuck how to do it
For simple line plots it's fine but i do like to use a kind of script that treats volt and temp bracket as vector matrix. Possibly a surface plot is a suitable choice

You need to describe your desired plot in more detail.  What is on the x axis? What is on the y axis? What numbers are you trying to pull out of the brackets to plot?  Like is it always "y value is taken from the third value in the first bracketed list"?   Should every row contribute to the plot or do you want to select only of the inventory tags for each date, or what?

There are voltage and temperature vary with time (first column ) that is typically x axis. The temp and volt are related parameters so it would be good to show them together but in the first try it could be good to show just a time series plot of voltage for each equipment as 2D plot for voltage and temperature separately (could be multiplot view)

@SinaAtabak I thought you wanted to plot all the 416 values in the brackets for each timestamp, but you accepted a solution which plots just column 4. What are all the other values in the brackets for?

Still not sure exactly what you have in mind, but here's a simple line plot (style "linespoints") that pulls the 2nd voltage value at each time point, one line for each instrument.  You don't provide enough data in your sample to make a reasonable demo as a fenceplot using plot style "zerror", but see  for example zerror documentation in User Manual.
# Line plot
# One line for each device numbered 1,4,5,6,7,10 in column 2
# Height of point at time t is 2nd value in first bracketed array

set datafile separator comma
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:S"

set xdata time
set xlabel "Time"
set xtics format "%H:%M"
set xtics 600.  # one tick mark every 10 minutes (600 seconds)
set xrange ["2024-04-11 18:00" : "2024-04-11 18:20"]

set ylabel "Instrument"   
set yrange [0:10]
set ytics (1,4,5,6,7,10)

set zlabel "Voltage point #2" rotate

set view 50,20

set style data linespoints
splot for [i=0:5] 'brackets.csv' using 1:2:4 every 6::i notitle



If that resolves your question, please mark the answer as "accepted" using the check-mark widget by the answer.
